# Why has to restart VS when updating a resource

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

recently I have been working on my app in Xamarain.android, as a part of school project.  I have noticed that every time I make a change in one of the Resource files (colors.xml , stirngs.xml , styles , drawable...) the layout file don't recognize the change unless I restart. So every time I make even a little change in one of those files, I have to restart VS. does anyone has a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Restart the debugging or VS ?

Comment: Are you using the latest Visual-Studio?

Comment: sure my vs is up to date

Comment: If you need to restart VS every time to update a resource, I would recommend you to repair VS or re-install VS.